# Countable partition in atoms

Tags: analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu: \Sigma \to [0, \infty)$ a measure over $\Omega$. We say a set $A \in \Sigma$ is an atom if for all $B \in \Sigma$ with $B \subset A$, $\mu(B)=\mu(A)$ or $\mu(B)=0$. We say that $\mu$ is atomic if every set $A \in \Sigma$ with positive measure contains an atom with positive measure.

So, I'm trying to prove that if $\mu$ is atomic, there exists $\{ A_n\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ pairwise disjoint atoms such that its union covers $\Omega$.

I can build a sequence this way:

Let $A \in \Sigma$ be a set with positive measure. It contains an atom $A_1$.Then I pick up $\Omega \setminus A_1$. Again, it contains an atom $A_2$ which is disjoint from $A_1$.

However, I do not know how to continue. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Choose at each step an atom with the biggest possible measure, which exists by finitness of the measure. This makes your algorithm stop in countably many steps. You can also have a look at [transfinite induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction) (which is not really necessary here but can be useful in similar problems, for example when there isn't a canonical choice at each step)

Comment: @Ramiro If the total measure is not finite it could be that there are atoms with arbitrarily large mass, for instance $\mu=\sum_n n\delta_n$ on the real line.

Comment: @del Yes, you are right. And if the measure is NOT finite, even if the atoms have bounded mass,  the result  may not hold.

Comment: @Del How is it that if my space is compact and the measure is finite and regular I can put $\mu=\sum_n n\delta_n$ for a certain sequence of elements?

Comment: @Whoknows I'm not sure I understand the question...I was replying to a former comment, to say that without the finiteness assumption on the measure there may not be a biggest atom

Comment: @Del As I have just commented below, I have been thinking about why it is possible to pick the biggest atom up, but I do not see it. Any hint?

Comment: @Whoknows Prove that $\mu$ is additive on atoms with different masses (no matter if they intersect or not). Then conclude using the finiteness of $\mu$ that there is a maximum for the masses of the atoms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For finite measures:**

**Proof**: If $\mu(\Omega) = 0$ the result is trivial, because $\Omega$ itself is an atom. Assume $\mu(\Omega) > 0$. Since $\mu$ is atomic, take $B_0=\Omega$ and define by induction, for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, if $\mu(B_n)>0$ then let $A_n \subseteq B_n$ be an atom with the largest possible measure among the atoms contained in $B_n$ (such choice of $A_n $ is always possible because the measure is finite) and let $B_{n+1}=B_n\setminus A_n$.

One of two things may happen:

1. For some $n_0\in  \mathbb{N}$, $\mu(B_{n_0+1})=0$ and in this case, $B_{n_0+1}$ is an atom, $A_0, \dots, A_{n_0}, B_{n_0+1}$ are disjoint atoms  and we have 
   $$\Omega = A_0 \cup \dots \cup A_{n_0} \cup B_{n_0+1}$$
   which proves the result (for this case).
2. For all $n\in  \mathbb{N}$, $\mu(B_{n})>0$. In this case we have an infinite sequence $\{A_n\}_{n\in  \mathbb{N}}$ of disjoint atoms of positive measures. Let 
   $$ A= \bigcup_{n\in  \mathbb{N}} A_n$$.

Claim: $\mu(\Omega \setminus A)=0$

Proof of the claim: if $\mu(\Omega \setminus A)>0$ the there is an atom $E\subseteq \Omega \setminus A$ such that $\mu(E)>0$. By our choice of $A_n$ at each step, we have that, for all $n\in  \mathbb{N}$ $\mu(A_n) \geqslant \mu(E)$. So $$ \mu(A)=\sum_{n\in  \mathbb{N}}\mu(A_n) =\infty$$
Contradiction, since the measure is finite.

So we proved  $\mu(\Omega \setminus A)=0$. So we have that $\Omega \setminus A$ is (trivially) an atom and we have 
$$\Omega =  \left ( \bigcup_{n\in  \mathbb{N}} A_n \right ) \cup (\Omega \setminus A)$$
So $\Omega$ is covered by a countable collection of atoms and this proves the result for this case and completes the proof.

**Remark:** if the measure is not finite, this result may not hold.

Consider $(\mathbb{R}, P(\mathbb{R}), \mu)$ where $\mu$ is the counting measure. Every singleton is an atom of positive measure. Any set with positive measure is not empty, so it contains a singleton, which means, it contains an atom of positive measure. So $\mu$ is atomic.

Note that the only atoms are the singletons (and the empty set), and clearly $\mathbb{R}$ is not a countable union of singletons.

**Remark 2**: Let us prove that, since $\mu$ is finite, the for any set $A$, if $A$ contain an atom, then there is an atom $E\subseteq A$ such that for any atom $F \subseteq A$, $\mu(F)\leqslant \mu(E)$.

Suppose  $A$ contain an atom. Let us prove the result by contradiction. Suppose that for all an atom $E\subseteq A$, there is an atom $F \subseteq A$, $\mu(F)> \mu(E)$.

Let $E_0\subseteq A$ is an atom. Then there is sequence of atoms $E_n\subseteq A$ such that for all $n\in \mathbb{N}$ $\mu(E_n) < \mu(E_{n+1})$.

Given any $i<j$, since $E_j$ is an atom and $\mu(E_i\cap E_j)\leqslant\mu(E_i) < \mu(E_j)$, we have that  $\mu(E_i\cap E_j)=0$. So we have

$$\mu \left ( \bigcup_{n\in  \mathbb{N}}E_n\right)= \sum_{n\in  \mathbb{N}}\mu(E_n)=+\infty$$

Contradiction, because the measure is finite.

So we proved that there is an atom $E\subseteq A$ such that for any atom $F \subseteq A$, $\mu(F)\leqslant \mu(E)$.

Comment: But that is not a finite measure. I'm working with finite ones.

Comment: @Whoknows You are right. For finite measures the result holds. I have updated my answer to show a detailed proof of such case.

Comment: I have been thinking about the fact that I can always choose the atom with the largest meassure among... However, I have not managed to prove it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Whoknows I updated my answer to include Remark 2. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Hints. First show that the set of atoms is countable. The show it must be (essentially) the whole space.

Comment: But if we take $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{P(\mathbb{R})},\mu)$, where $\mu(A)=1$ if $0 \in A$ and $\mu(A)=0$ otherwise, every set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is an atom. Therefore, the set of atoms does not have to be countable.

Comment: I think you're right, and my method may not work. I have to read the question more carefully, but don't have time now. I may leave this false start up for a while, delete it later.